# Export svg with same gradient stops

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How to export svg from illustrator so that no extra gradient stops added,except added by me.

I am trying to export svg from illustrator, it adds extra gradient stops in exported svg. Say I have a square filled with radial gradient with 3 stops(including start and end). In exported svg it has 12 stops in the same radial gradient. What settings should I apply in illustrator, so that exported(saved) svg has optimal gradient information , and avoid illustrator adding extra stops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a mistake in your gradient or in the way you export the svg. I reproduced in Illustrator exactly what you describe, a square with a radial gradient and three stops, and this is the result:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
<defs>
<style>.cls-1{fill:url(#radial-gradient);}</style>
<radialGradient id="radial-gradient" cx="147.5" cy="147.5" r="147.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#fcee21"/>
<stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#f0f"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#f15a24"/>
</radialGradient></defs>
<title>Asset 3</title>
<g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">
<rect class="cls-1" width="295" height="295"/></g></g></svg>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/danielillo/full/PoojEPK)

In your other question you say you are working with an image downloaded from the internet. If you continue with the same image and don't know how it's done, I recommend you make a test with a vector made from scratch in a new file.

**Edit after the comment**

The reason why there are many stops is because the right part of the gradient has the **gradient slider** in a different position than the default one: 50%. This causes the svg to restructure the entire gradient:

[image]

Modifying the gradient to get a similar result **without touching the gradient sliders** gives a result with as many stops as colors the gradient has:

[image]

Comment: Hi, here is the file i am working with.[Sample file](http://daylets.com/Sample_[Converted].ai) . Also i tried 'select all' → 'copy everything' and paste in new document. It did not worked. Settings I used for save as svg [settings](http://daylets.com/i5.png)

Comment: Answer updated with more info

Comment: There is something more, as I commented when I copy everything and paste it to new file, the outer black stop in the new file creates white shadow instead black. What may be the reason for this?

Comment: You are pasting in a new **CMYK** document when it must be **RGB**.

Comment: The whole problem was that, i could not figure out. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Danielillo there still one problem exists, sample file is also in rgb mode and inkscape works well with rgb mode, but exported svg not looking same in inkscape.